# Как заставить BottomNavigationItem занимать все доступное место?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я хочу сделать BottomNavigation, такой, чтобы при нажатии в выбранном айтеме появлялся текст рядом с иконкой. Как можно заставить BottomNavigationItem пододвигать другие айтемы при выборе, чтобы текст не переносился?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так:

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(
    items: List<BottomNavItem>,
    navController: NavController,
    onItemClick: (BottomNavItem) -> Unit
) {
    val backStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    BottomNavigation(
        modifier = Modifier,
        elevation = 0.dp,
        backgroundColor = light
    ) {
        items.forEach{
            val selected = it.screen_route == backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = selected,
                selectedContentColor = primary_color,
                unselectedContentColor = shaded,
                onClick = { onItemClick(it) },
                icon = {
                    Row(
                        modifier = if (selected) Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 15.dp)
                        else Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 15.dp)
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = it.icon,
                            contentDescription = it.title,
                            tint = if (selected) primary_color else shaded,

                            )
                        if (selected){
                            Text(
                                text = it.title,
                                color = primary_color,
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                fontSize = 20.sp,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 2.dp).align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                                overflow = TextOverflow.Visible
                            )
                        }
                    }

                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему бы не сделать текст под иконкой?

Comment: @vitidev так смотрится лучше и места меньше занимает вертикально, но если не получится, то сделаю текст снизу

Comment: "смотрится лучше"....ну разве что остальное сжимается в кнопки, а текущий элемент занимает все оставшееся пространство путем выставления `Modifier.weight(1f)` у текущего.

Comment: @vitidev не получается, пробовал добавить к Row и к BottomNavigationItem если выбраны

Comment: Не получается из-за реализации `BottomNavigationItem`. Он всем выставляет `.weight(1f)` чтобы были равные колонки. Вам придется сделать свою реализацию `BottomNavigationItem`

Comment: @vitidev, спасибо, все заработало